# Accepting android licenses for Flutter not working

Tags: flutter

I am trying to install flutter to use it Visual Studio Code. I installed Git, flutter SDK, set ENV variables... but when I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the licenses I get this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema                                  
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)                            
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)                                                 
at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)                                  
at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)                                         
at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)                                 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema                                                
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)                              
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)                           
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)                                                      
... 5 more
```

I have OpenJDK installed. If you need detail here is my `flutter doctor -v` output :

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.630], locale en-GB)                           
• Flutter version 1.22.4 at C:\Users\cleme\AppData\Local\flutter                                                        
• Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (2 weeks ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800                                                
• Engine revision 2c956a31c0                                                                                            
• Dart version 2.10.4                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)                                            
• Android SDK at C:\Users\cleme\AppData\Local\Android\sdk                                                               
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2                                                                               
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java                                                  
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)                                           
X Android license status unknown.                                                                                         
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.                                                     
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.                                                                                                                                                  
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)                                                                                          
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio                                                             
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.                                               
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.                                                     
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)                                                                                                                                                               
[!] Connected device                                                                                                        
! No devices available                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out where does this error come from. I had OpenJDK 11 Hotspot installed on my Windows system with JAVA_HOME variable associated to its path. After removing OpenJDK and rebooting everything worked fine because flutter could use its own java file/dirs...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like You've not installed the dart plugin.

Follow this to install dart plugin:

Start VS Code. Invoke View > Command Palette. Type “install”, and select Extensions: Install Extensions. Type “flutter” in the extensions search field, select Flutter in the list, and click Install.

Comment: Yes but that's not the problem since I won't be able to do anything with licenses not accepted. But I installed flutter and dart extension... As expected it did not change anything : I still get the same error when running flutter doctor --android-licenses

Answer (score 0):

**Install Java:**

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-doc
```

Then flutter doctor --android-licenses works fine:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
Warning: File /home/daniel/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.       
5 of 6 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...             
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)?
```